# Publishing .NET Core C# self-contained application for linux architecture

Tags: c#, .net, linux, windows, .net-core

So I'm trying to host a discord bot on a Google Cloud Server. I've got a base-level bot that works and runs from my local machine.
The bot is written in C# .NET Core framework for Windows 10 x64.

Before anyone says it's been solved before, I have found those solutions and nothing is helping me.

I'm trying to publish the .NET application to a linux format self-contained. So that I can deploy and run the bot on the linux server (Ubuntu 18.04-x64 [I cross-checked on the .NET website to make sure it was a deployable package])
I looked it up and found the command, and also the changes I had to make inside my .vsproj file.

[image: publishing error]

[image: .csproj file]

Is anyone able to walk me through something I'm missing? Do I have to download the linux version of something to build for it... or whatever. I'm not really sure what I'm missing. Then from that, I know how to upload the files to my server, but how do I "remotely" execute the deployed application on the server?

Comment: Post the *text* not the screenshot. The LTS version is 2.1 in any case, so you should change `netcoreapp2.0` to `netcoreapp2.1`. The package versions used in that screenshot target 2.2, currently in preview 3. All this matters because a) you'll have to target 2.1 anyway and b) a lot of issues were fixed on 2.1 and many more on 2.2

Comment: The process is described in [Deploying apps with CLI tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli) the error though complains about an incorrect RID. I suspect the 2.0 build tools didn't contain that RID. Try publishing using the *supported* Core version

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll try that.

Comment: So I tried changing it to netcoreapp2.1 and it won't even run from Visual Studio. And when I try the console publish I get this error:

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(135,5): error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1. [D:\Github\Bots\Chill_Bot\Chill_Bot.csproj]

Comment: Make sure you only target 2.1 packages for the 2.1 runtime, do you have recent versions of the tooling? (what is your `dotnet --info` output?)

Comment: @JackMcCall You need to have .Net Core 2.1 SDK installed. Here's the link https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.1

Comment: can you make sure your version is `2.1.500` and your visual studio is up-to-date? (VS version is `15.9.2`)

Comment: Additionally, you no longer need the `<RuntimeIdentifiers>` xml tag in the csproj file, it doesn't have any effect anymore..

Comment: Oh, ok. So just the output type and the framework?

Comment: @JackMcCall as the error says `or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1`. Install the SDK. You probably need to upgrade Visual Studio itself if it doesn't already inculde .NET 2.1. The latest upgrade is 15.9.2

Comment: Ah wait no you said 2.1.5 ok thanks

Comment: @JackMcCall the .NET Core downloads [are here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.1). The list shows which runtime is included in which VS version as well

Comment: Thanks for all of your help guys. I'm new to using linux, and it's been a while (probably around 8 months or so) since I've coded at all, so yeah that was the little voice in the back of my head wondering if something somewhere was out of date. But after staying up late trudging through setting up the server, and dredging up the ol' coding cobwebs the obvious solutions seem to have escaped me

Comment: I'm running the updates now, so hopefully that was the only problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those who commented. Performed the update for my .NET Core framework to 2.1.500 and hey presto! Successfully published the application.